# Fetch MongoDB + Express + NodeJS + React

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

I'm trying a project MERN, I'm new in this environment I want to fetch data from MongoDB->NodeJS->Express->React. So, this is my server.js file in a NodeJs project:

> server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const url = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/'
var router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var db
MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
  if (err){
    return console.log(err);
  }else{
    console.log('Connection established to', url);
  db = client.db('database-test') 
  app.listen(3100, () => {
    console.log('listening on 3100')
  })}
});

app.get('/quotes', (req, res) => {
  db.collection('quotes').find({_name :'Henry'}).next(function(err, doc)
{
  if(err)
  console.log(err);
  res.json(doc);
})
});
```

with a GET I want to fetch my data from a MongoBD collection called quotes:

> MongoDB query

```
db.quotes.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aa94f93bd03af418d4d0acf"), "name" : "Henry" }
```

Now I want to show my data in a ReactJS project, so I used a proxy to redirect the call to nodeJS Project

> ReactJS project, file package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3100"
}
```

and in App.js file I want to show my data

> ReactJS project, App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
const URL = 'http://localhost:3100'

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    quotes: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/quotes')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(quotes => this.setState({ quotes }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
         <div className="App">
           <header className="App-header">
             <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
             <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
           </header>
           <p className="App-intro">{this.name.response}</p>
         </div>
       );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What I would like to know is what is the right way to do it,
how to query my DB in the server.js file and how to call it from the App.js file to show my data. Obviously what I have in my code doesn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I do not see the data from browser and I do not know if the way I fetch is correct.

Comment: The fetch looks fine, could you check the console for any errors? And do a `console.log(quotes)` in the fetch request to see what data is coming in?

Comment: @FabianSchultz for you as I call the response in React in correct?

this one: ` <p className="App-intro">{this.name.response}</p>`

Comment: Check the console of the browser. You probably want something like this: `{this.state.quotes[0] ? this.state.quotes[0].name : null}`

Comment: The console of the browser return 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined
    at App.render (App.js:24) ......
   

The way as I make the query is correct because now I see in the log my json '{ _id: 5aa94f93bd03af418d4d0acf, name: 'Henry', quote: 'quote' }

Comment: Where do you set `this.name`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you saved the URL as a variable at the top of your App.js file, but never called it in your fetch function.